# PyMySql query in async function

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, tornado, pymysql

I'm using [tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado) framework to write a non-blocking API.

I want to make asynchronous mysql queries, for this purpose should I use asynchronous mysql libraries (for tornado) or can I use something like this?

```
import tornado.web
import pymysql
import json


class AsyncDBCalls(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        database = {
            "host": "localhost",
            "user": "root",
            "password": "123456",
            "db": "tableName",
            "cursorclass": pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
            "autocommit": True,
            "charset": "utf8"
        }
        try:
            self.db_connection = pymysql.connect(**database)
            self.db = self.db_connection.cursor()
        except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
            pass
            # TODO logging

    async def make_query(self, query):
        self.db.execute(query)
        results = self.db.fetchall()
        return results

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    async def get(self):
        query = "SELECT * FROM users"
        results = await self.make_query(query)
        self.set_status(200)
        self.add_header("Content-Type", "text/json")
        self.write(json.dumps(results))
        self.finish()
```

Is this *make_query* function running asynchronous? Is this code can be used for non-blocking API?

Comment: No, `PyMySQL` isn't async. So, it would block the Tornado server. But you can use [`aiomysql`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql). It is built upon `PyMySQL`, so you won't have to learn a whole lot of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TorMySQL](https://github.com/snower/TorMySQL) instead.

You should also consider using connection pool since you would have to use more that one connection:

```
self.pool = tormysql.ConnectionPool(
        max_connections=256,
        wait_connection_timeout=5,
        idle_seconds=7200,
        host=<host>,
        db=<database>,
        user=<user>,
        passwd=<password>,
        cursorclass=tormysql.cursor.DictCursor,
        autocommit=True,
        use_unicode=True,
        charset="utf8",
        **kwargs
    )

connection = yield self.pool.Connection()
...
# this actually will not close the connection, but put back into pool
connection.close()
```

You can steal this [gist](https://gist.github.com/desertkun/2a91c297e311c50006e1ffea530b1a3f). It will do pool handling for you. With it you can either do:

```
db.query("SELECT ..");
```

for atomic operations, or get the connection from the pool for more complicated stuff:

```
with (yield db.acquire(auto_commit=False)) as db:
    row = yield db.get("SELECT ... FOR UPDATE");
    ...
    yield db.execute("UPDATE ...");
    yield db.commit()
```

Comment: I tried aiomysql which is @xyres mentioned before. But I can not figure out how to pass cursor object to requesthandlers. aiomysql's create pool function is an async function. I can not call it in Application __init__.
If I try TorMySQL how can achieve this? For example I create a pool in application __init__. I want to create a connection cursor in requesthandler's initialize method. But initialize method is not an async method so I can not call `yield self.application.pool.Connection()` in it. What's your advice for this. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @RasimAndıran see [add_callback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback). It is coroutine-ready, so you can do `IOLoop.current().add_callback(your_async_init)`